# Convert Callback to suspendable coroutine in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I currently have a callback that instead of returning a value synchronously, it will need to do some async work and then return the result. I've been investigating about how to do it but I don't get thing clear. What I have achieved until now is this, but as I need to put a return into foo method, at first it returns "something" and afterthat return the result of calling someMethod().

Is it possible to to what I'm pretending?

```
  class CustomClass() :
    SomeClass.SomeInterface {

    override fun foo(p0: SomeType): String {
      val result = "something"
      MainScope().launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
          result = someMethod()
        }
      }
      return result
    }

    suspend fun someMethod(): String =
      suspendCancellableCoroutine { cancelableContinuation ->
        //TODO: register some listener that will end up calling 
        cancelableContinuation.resume("some_value", {})
      }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean your method will return different kinds of states or values? If yes, you may be looking for a `Flow`.

Comment: No, it should only return a value each time the callback is called

Answer (score 3):

You cannot return the result synchronously, so `foo` has to be defined as a suspend function.

Also, there's no reason to wrap a suspend function call in `withContext`. Suspend functions (if composed correctly) internally wrap any blocking code so they are safe to call from any dispatcher, so there's no reason to specify one using `withContext`

If you strip away the `withContext` and the launching of the coroutine that you weren't waiting for, `foo()` does nothing besides calling `someMethod`, so you can just move that code from `someMethod` into `foo`. But `foo` must be defined as a `suspend` function.

```
override suspend fun foo(p0: SomeType): String = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    val request = someApi.request(p0) { result: String ->
        continuation.resume(result)
    }
    continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
        request.cancel()
    }
}
```

Generally you don't want model classes like this launching coroutines from their own CoroutineScopes. Just have them expose suspend functions. It's up to the higher level classes like Activity, Fragment, and ViewModel to launch coroutines from their desired scopes so they can control the coroutine lifecycles.

Comment: "You cannot return the result synchronously, so foo has to be defined as a suspend function", Sorry but I'm missing something  with your response. If if write something like you mentioned, I'm getting the warning "Suspend function 'suspendCancellableCoroutine' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function". The point is that I'm working with React Native so I'm not aware of the lifecycle of the Activity/Fragment or ViewModel. What I'm trying to do is to delegate managing this to some object that extends an interface and to return its value I need an async operation.

Comment: I forgot to mention, `foo` itself has to be a suspend function. So you'd have to define it as `suspend` in the interface. When you call `foo` you would do it from a coroutine launched from the source. If you're working with an Activity/Fragment, that's typically `lifecycleScope` or `viewLifecycleScope`, or in a ViewModel, that's `viewModelScope`. You don't have to be intimately familiar with the various lifecycles to use these. They automatically cancel when their lifecycles are over.

Comment: Ok, thanks the point is that I don't own the interface SomeClass.SomeInterface so I can't modify foo become a suspend function.

Comment: Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Your `foo` function is basically synchronous, so what's happening is that you launch a `suspendable` don't wait for it's result and return the initial value of result (`"something"`)

You have multiple options for making sure, foo waits for the response from `someMethod`, for ex:

- Make `foo` a `suspend fun
- Use a callback, for example:

```
override fun foo(p0: SomeType, onResult: (String) -> Unit): String {
      MainScope().launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
          onResult(someMethod())
        }
      }
    }

// Call it like this:
foo(p0) { result ->
    // handle result
}
```