# How can I get runBlocking in Kotlin to work correctly?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, blocking

My goal here is to have loadInformationFromFirestore, which reads data from a Firestore database, complete before the code after it (here just a Timber logging message) is executed.  When I run getGroupSummaries, these are the logging messages I see:

> After loadUserInformationFromFirestore in runBlocking

> After loadUserInformationFromFirestore after runBlocking

> In LoadUserInformationFromFirestore

This says to me that "runBlocking" is not blocking at all -- the runBlocking returns before LoadUserInformationFromFirestore completes. Any advice would be appreciated.

```kt
var mFirestore: FirebaseFirestore? = null

fun getGroupSummaries(groupInfo: GroupInformation, adminUserInfo: UserInformation) {
    mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    val uid = "3iHWCsGmKvfq4w9OgDNWZsSs8wy2"

    runBlocking {
        val loadUserInformationJob = viewModelScope.launch { loadUserInformationFromFirestore(uid) }
        loadUserInformationJob.join()
        Timber.d("After loadUserInformationFromFirestore in runBlocking")
    }
    Timber.d("After loadUserInformationFromFirestore after runBlocking")
}

suspend fun loadUserInformationFromFirestore(uid: String) {
    try {
        // Get document from Firestore
        val docRef =
            mFirestore!!.collection("Users").document(uid).collection("UserProfile").document(uid)

        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val document = task.result
                if (document.exists()) {
                    Timber.d("In LoadUserInformationFromFirestore")
                } else if (!document.exists()) {
                    Timber.e(
                        "In LoadInformationFromFirestore, User document does not exist. Send user through into questions."
                    )
                } else {
                    Timber.e("In LoadInformationFromFirestore, Error loading user document")
                }
            } else {
                Timber.e(
                    "In LoadInformationFromFirestore, get Firestore failed with ",
                    task.exception
                )
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.w("Error getting Firebase User", e)
    }
}
```

Comment: `addOnCompleteListener()` isn't a coroutine. It adds a listener, not returns a value

Comment: How did you come to a conclusion 'This says to me that "runBlocking" is not blocking at all'? Instead this actually suggests `loadUserInformationFromFirestore` has returned before `In LoadUserInformationFromFirestore` is logged. And the reason is obvious, `"In LoadUserInformationFromFirestore"` is logged in the onComplete listener, which is not awaited. You should use something like `suspendCoroutine` to [convert callback to suspend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67632814/convert-callback-to-suspendable-coroutine-in-kotlin).

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is related to the asynchronous nature of Firestore callbacks. The `addOnCompleteListener` callback inside `loadUserInformationFromFirestore` is asynchronous, and runBlocking doesn't wait for it to complete.

You can use `suspendCoroutine` or `suspendCancellableCoroutine` to convert the asynchronous Firestore task into a suspendable coroutine. This way, you can ensure that the runBlocking coroutine will wait for the Firestore task to complete before moving on.

See here:

```
var mFirestore: FirebaseFirestore? = null

fun getGroupSummaries(groupInfo: GroupInformation, adminUserInfo: UserInformation) {
    mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    val uid = "3iHWCsGmKvfq4w9OgDNWZsSs8wy2"

    runBlocking {
        try {
            val userInformation = loadUserInformationFromFirestore(uid)
            Timber.d("After loadUserInformationFromFirestore in runBlocking")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e("Error loading user information", e)
        }
    }
    Timber.d("After loadUserInformationFromFirestore after runBlocking")
}

suspend fun loadUserInformationFromFirestore(uid: String): UserInformation = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    try {
        // Get document from Firestore
        val docRef =
            mFirestore!!.collection("Users").document(uid).collection("UserProfile").document(uid)

        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val document = task.result
                if (document.exists()) {
                    Timber.d("In LoadUserInformationFromFirestore")
                    // Assuming UserInformation is a class you want to return
                    continuation.resume(UserInformation(/* populate with data */))
                } else {
                    Timber.e("In LoadInformationFromFirestore, User document does not exist.")
                    continuation.resumeWithException(DocumentNotFoundException("User document not found"))
                }
            } else {
                Timber.e("In LoadInformationFromFirestore, get Firestore failed with ", task.exception)
                continuation.resumeWithException(task.exception ?: RuntimeException("Unknown error"))
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.w("Error getting Firebase User", e)
        continuation.resumeWithException(e)
    }
}

class DocumentNotFoundException(message: String) : RuntimeException(message)
```

*Here, the runBlocking coroutine will wait for the Firestore task to complete before moving on to the next line. Additionally, it handles exceptions and provides a more structured way of returning the result.*

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: Firebase already provides the `await()` suspend function you can use. Don’t need to rebuild it yourself.